# Car Rental vs Grab/Uber for getting around Ubud/Kuta/Seminyak in Bali

Tags: bali, uber

As above. I went to Bali 2 years back and remember it was quite challenging getting Grab/Uber to stop at popular tourist spots, as the taxi drivers are violent against them.

May I check whether it is still the same?

In addition, we are travelling long distance, say from Airport to Ubud. Will drivers be willing to take long trips?

Thanks!

Comment: Just take a legal taxi?  The taxi drivers are right.  Ubers business model is to evade taxi law and labour law, paying far less than minimum wage even where such a minimum wage exists.

Comment: @gerrit cab drivers only care about maintaining a monopoly, rather than about what wages are paid by the competition

Comment: @JonathanReez I expect cab drivers care about maintaining their regulated fares, and not being undercut by unregulated/illegal taxis. An English union activist put it very well when he pointed out that Uber benefits from a wide availability of Uber cars by drivers driving around empty waiting for passengers, without Uber paying those drivers anything for this service. For legal taxis, regulated fares are supposed to take this into account, hence minimum prices. And I don't know about Indonesia, but in most places I've lived, there are many competing taxi companies, certainly no monopoly.

Comment: none of the comments above are relevant to the question. appreciate if everyone can stick to the topic.

Answer (score 3):

I've travelled there recently and may be of help.

Uber is a no-no in Bali. People still don't like Uber there. And the app doesn't really work there.

Alternatives:

1. Bluebird
2. Grab
3. Private Cabs

You can use **Bluebird** or **Grab** for cab bookings. Bluebird is a bit costlier than Grab. We have faced no issues with either of these cabs while travelling to places long distances as well, and we used these both services a LOT.

I found that both Grab and Bluebird don't service in some areas like Sukawati and Giyanyar (better to hire locals or rent bikes if you're planning to visit these areas). And would always suggest private drivers if your taking a full day tour (non-commercial, informative and friendly for long tours)

If you're heading to airport from Seminyak, Kuta, Ubud go for Grab or Bluebird

If you're heading to the airport from places further from these three, better hire a local driver (your hotel will have contacts with local drivers) or utilise the hotel's cabs.

**Ubud, Seminyak and Kuta are quite serviceable and we were able to book a cab from Ubud to Airport immediately without any hassles in Bluebird**

**Additional Info:**

You can haggle with local drivers to reduce the price of the ride.

Most of the Grab/Bluebird drivers don't respond to cab bookings post 9 PM even though they are very close by. They do this to take people for private ride with increased cost.

A day ride with a local driver for 8 to 12 hours should cost you about 600000 Rupiah. They're cheaper and the drivers are more informed.